# Rotate Individual Origins Of An Array Of Faces With Proportional Editing On

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to rotate an array of faces with with proportionally edit on:

1. Each face needs to rotate on its on individual origin.
2. Proportional editing should gradually diminish rotation from the first to last faces.

I am blocking out the vertebrae of the human spine.

L1 faces (the unhidden faces) need to be rotated and L2 - L5 should inherit this rotation but L2 - L5 must inherit the rotation in diminishing amounts and must rotate on their individual origins.

How do I do this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Even with proportional editing on, any selected geometry will be transformed 100% by your action. Hidden faces and geometry not affected by proportional editing.

Fix:

- Set your Axis and Pivot Point settings (probably `normal` and `individual origins`)
- Select all the faces you want to be rotated by any ammount
- do `Hide Unselected` with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to protect everything else
- Enable proportional editing and select **only** the faces where you want maximum rotation
- `Rotate` and ajust the proportional range with scroll wheel

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand but if your trying to rotate on the faces origin just change pivot point to individual origins.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you should select all faces make vertex group, then switch to "individual origins" pivot by holding "." and find a setting that allows you to only affect the vertex group. Then select only one of the faces and rotate it with proportional editing. The effect should be that it only affects the faces in vertex group, rotates them by individual origins and gradually rotate less as they get further away from selected face. I don't know how to only affect the vertex group tho. Possibly something to do with masking or field weights